# OR Clause in SQL Server LEFT JOIN causing high logical reads

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I rewrite the below query by eliminating the OR clause

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Value-T2.value as value 
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.ID=T1.ID OR T2.OLD_ID=T1.ID
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on `TABLE2`?

Answer (score 3):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL QUESTION.

`OR` causes major problems in joins.  You can very easily fix this query.  Basically, this should do what you want:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TABLE1 T1;
```

Why?  You are selecting no rows from the second table and the `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table.  There is the possibility of duplicate rows, but I'm guessing that you don't want duplicates (an assumption on my part).

Comment: that is the sample query i given... the actual query selects some rows from T2 also

Comment: sorry, due to some permission problems i am unable to paste the original one.

Comment: You don't have to paste the original one, just reflect in your example that you need columns from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try `IN` instead:

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.value - T2.value AS value
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID IN (T2.ID, T2.OLD_ID)
```

### Edit

Another version, with multiple `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.value - COALESCE(T2A.value, T2B.value) AS value
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2A ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2B ON T1.ID = T2.OLD_ID
```

Yet another version:

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.value - T2.value AS value
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID, value FROM TABLE2 UNION
            SELECT OLD_ID, value FROM TABLE2 ) T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: Well, the `=` operator used in the original query has the same problem with `NULL`s...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to write it, though I don't know if will affect the logical reads:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Value-T2.value as value 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 
 ON T2.ID=T1.ID 
UNION ALL 
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Value-T2.value as value 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 
 ON T2.ID<>T1.ID
 AND T2.OLD_ID=T1.ID
```

Comment: I am getting duplicate records

Comment: using UNION instead of UNION ALL gives correct out put. But the performance is too slow